# Firebase Cloud Function Log. I can't see all my data in the log

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Function with Node.js. With the function console.log(req.body) I want to save in the log of Firebase the data to see it then.

The problem is that data isn't complete.

[image]

As you can see the json end with the word "curr" but it should continue.

I try to see the log from the console but the message is the same:

[image]

Can I change the max size to show in the log?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's a limit to how much data that can be shown in a single line, and you're exceeding it.  You could consider breaking it up in to multiple lines, but it's probably easiest if you use the [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) to make it easier to debug your functions before you deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log()` cannot display messages that are too long, or contain certain classes (which are then just shown as `[somthing Object]`)

**Use** `functions.logger.log()` instead.